# Problems with a multidimensional principal value numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

### Multidimensional Principal Value Computation

Hi all, I've been trying to work out a type of integral for... months? Years? I've scoured the documentation here, and tried several of the tips in other solutions, but nothing has worked. Here's the typical integral I'm trying to compute:

[image: The numerator is a function of the integration variables. I am more or less sure I've isolated the term where the singularity is coming from.]

I believe I've isolated the singularity in the $l^+$ integration, namely it occurs in the $l^+-l^+_+[l^\perp, \psi]$ term. (For example, when $\psi = 1$ and $l^\perp =2$, $l^+_+$ equals some number that is between $q^{\prime +}$ and $\delta^+$, which by the way are simply numbers in my computation.

Here's the integrand of the principal value integral I'm trying to evaluate:

```
-((0.14644660940672627*(2.*lplus - 4.48528137423857))/((lplus - 
   0.10717927578284499)*lplus*
     ((0.5*(lperp^2*Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 + 
        19.31370849898476*(lplus - 1.6568542494923801) + 
        15.21))/(lplus - 1.6568542494923801) - 
        (0.5*(lperp^2*Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 + 
        3.61))/lplus)*
     ((0.5*(lperp^2*Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 + 
        19.31370849898476*(lplus - 1.6568542494923801) + 
        15.21))/(lplus - 1.6568542494923801) - 
        (0.5*((lperp*Sin[\[Psi]] - 
           0.046107085839748325)^2 + (lperp*Cos[\[Psi]] - 
           0.02661993842112788)^2 + 
        8.98713372945139*(lplus - 0.10717927578284499) + 3.61))/
          (lplus - 0.10717927578284499))*
     (0.07322330470336312*(-(1.*
         Sqrt[27.31370849898476*(0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*
               Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + 
              0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 - 
              23.09018828369476) + 
                      938.0386719675122]) - 30.62741699796951) + 
   lplus)*
     (0.07322330470336312*(Sqrt[
       27.31370849898476*(0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*
            Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + 
           0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 - 
           23.09018828369476) + 
                 938.0386719675122] - 30.62741699796951) + 
   lplus)))
```

(This is the input form of the output of a function which I named `McintII1plusmod[lperp, lplus, \[Psi]]`)

Then typically I'd try to integrate it numerically with some sort of strategy, for instance this is the AdaptiveMonteCarlo method I tried just to get a poor estimate of the result ($qplf[[1]] = 0.1, \delta lf[[1]]=1.7$, approximately):

```
    Mean@Table[
   NIntegrate[
    lperp*McintII1plusmod[lperp, lplus, \[Psi]], {lperp, 0, 
     Infinity}, {\[Psi], 0, 2 Pi}, {lplus, 
     qplf[[1]], \[Delta]lf[[1]]}, 
    Exclusions -> lplus - lplusplus12func2[lperp, \[Psi]] == 0, 
    Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 10000000, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 2], {40}] // Timing

Out[1533]= {38.5, 0.945978}
```

By the way, technically the integrand I'm evaluating supposedly has infinite Precision, because I defined everything while constructing it exactly with the help of Rationalize. However, I don't think the output was very friendly for this forum with its towering fractions. (But if it would help to provide it, I can with a later edit.)

When I used GlobalAdaptive methods (and explicitly tried to put the singularity on integration boundaries with Boole, Exclusions->, etc.) it would evaluate, but for instance GlobalAdaptive methods would give me like 1.007 with Sqrt[.14^2+.2^2]-like error estimates. (And I did fiddle around with PrecisionGoal, MaxErrorIncreases, etc.) Trying LocalAdaptive stuff didn't seem to do the trick either.

By the way, this is a 3D plot of what my integrand looks like with $\psi =1$ ($l^\perp$ only shown between 0 and 2, but for large $l^\perp$ the integrand approaches 0):

[image]

It does seem to me not-unreasonable to hope for some sort of symmetric cancelling to occur and for my integral to converge.

I've thought about it for a while, and I'm wondering if I'm getting errors because *Mathematica* might not know exactly where the singularity is occurring (perhaps only to MachinePrecision), because I seem to get similar levels of error if I don't specify *precisely* the singularity in 1D Principal Value integrations. However, I don't know how I can specify the singular part more specifically, because my $l^+_+$ function supposedly has infinite precision already!

I'm also somewhat averse to trying to work with this integral analytically, because this is one of dozens in my research Notebook, and each one will need to be evaluated for different kinematic values, so if I could get an accurate numerical solution, that would be ideal.

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'd like to get near MachinePrecision results if possible, because I have a "reasonableness check" at the end where the result should be exactly 0, so it would be nice to see something like $10^{-12}$ or less there as I do have 30-50 integrals to evaluate or so.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!! Please let me know if any more information is needed and/or would be helpful.

Edit: I just realized that I should provide the function to exclude. Use

```
Exclusions -> (0.07322330470336312*(Sqrt[
     27.31370849898476*(0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*
          Sin[\[Psi]]^2 + 
         0.5857864376269051*lperp^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2 - 
         23.09018828369476) + 938.0386719675122] - 
    30.62741699796951) + lplus) == 0]
```

Comment: I have never seen any definition of a principal value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value for an $n$-idimensional integral over a bounded domain when the singularity of the integrand is not a single point in  $n$ dimensions . A reference is welcome.

Comment: @user64494 Focusing at least for now on the real part, you can see examples of multidimensional singularity integration in the documentation [link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html) at the "Curve, Surface, and Hypersurface Singularities" section.

Comment: @user64494 To get the imaginary part, I used the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) Kramers Kronig relations. I don't think what I did is invalid; I still have a single point in principle, but it's shifting as the arguments of the other integrations shift it.

Sorry for the double comment, accidentally sent my last comment without realizing I only get 5 minutes to edit!

Comment: Can you present a concrete example from the linked documentation (of big size)? TIA.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any imaginary part in the integrand under consideration.